# Unrestricted length for user input

Tags: asp.net, security, user-input

During security review of our asp.net web application we got reported that some input fields **doesn't restrict length of user input** on server side. There is said in execution report that this vulnerability can be used to consume large amount of resources in the server or database which can cause Denial of Service attacks.

I would like to ask what options are here to fix this. Of course we can implement the validation on web server side for every field and e.g. throw some exception and reject if input is longer then some predefined value. But I am curious if there is some more other ways how to do it. Maybe some configuration in web.config or on IIS server level, some global handler etc.

Comment: what do u want. Do u want to restrict character length of input controls?

Comment: yes, I would like to restrict number of characters which user can enter to some maximum. Usually user doesn't enter more that e.g. 100 characters in single form field. As finding says user should not be able to enter large amount of data e.g more than 1K of characters in input field. I am looking for options how to do the validation on server side. Ideally by configuration or some generic way for all other fields.

Comment: u can set the maxlength="30" property of controls.

Comment: That is just client side and can be easily removed from rendered html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`maxRequestLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) setting in web.config.

> Specifies the limit for the input stream buffering threshold, in KB. This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are caused, for example, by users posting large files to the server.
>   The default is 4096 (4 MB).

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This would be a better solution than restricting each individual field as it is protecting your application as a whole as it sounds like they haven't found any specific inputs that are vulnerable.

If you want this to only apply to certain sections of your application you could add an override using the `<location>` element:

```
<location path="Attachments/Upload">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I still want to do some testing but changes on this level are most probably not possible as the application supports upload of attachments and this is key settings to allow it.

Comment: Answer updated for how you can configure it for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks - just tested suggested configuratin and it looks promissing.